# Крылатые слова и поговорки с похожим смыслом

Tags: лексика, фразеология

Например, ситуация: "У предмета есть либо одно качество, но нет другого. Либо наоборот. А так, чтобы оба сразу - не нахожу."
Подскажите, какая поговорка или крылатая фраза тут была бы уместна? Что-то вроде "халата с перламутровыми пуговицами".)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Могу предложить следующие варианты:

*Если бы губы Никанора Ивановича да приставить к носу Ивана Кузьмича* (из пьессы Н. В. Гоголя "Женитьба").
*Кабы Иван Великий был маленький, а карман у меня большой, я б его туда посадил* - пословица.

Answer (score 2):

Лис очень удивился:
- На другой планете?
- Да.
- А на той планете есть охотники?
- Нет.
- Как интересно! А куры есть?
- Нет.
- Нет в мире совершенства! - вздохнул Лис.
Антуан де Сент-Экзюпери, "Маленький принц"